# Questions/Problems related to set-winuserlanguagelist command

Tags: powershell

I'm building a code to fix keyboard layout situation on windows 10. With automated solution, I decided to use powershell. But the problem is that I'm pretty new in it and face certain problems. I managed to dig a script to change keyboard layouts, however it changes only to one language. As I try to create array with 2 languages:

```
$langlist=$lang_en,$lang_ru
set-winuserlanguagelist $langlist
```

It simply returns me next error:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage' to the type
'Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage' required by parameter 'LanguageList'. Specified method is
not supported.
At line:1 char:25
+ set-winuserlanguagelist $langlist
+                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-WinUserLanguageList], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.SetWinUserLanguageListCommand
```

When I tried to use next command: `$test = Get-WinUserLanguageList`, the command works well with `set-winuserlanguagelist`.

The full script:

```
$keys='0809:00020409', '0419:00000419'

$lang_en=new-winuserlanguagelist en-gb
$lang_en[0].inputmethodtips.clear()
$lang_en[0].inputmethodtips.add($keys[0])

$lang_ru=new-winuserlanguagelist ru
$lang_ru[0].inputmethodtips.clear()
$lang_ru[0].inputmethodtips.add($keys[1])

$langlist=$lang_en,$lang_ru

set-winuserlanguagelist $langlist
```

Comment: Question is no longer actual. The reason behind the problem was type of the variable. I declared it wrong way. The right way was: `$langlist = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]"`

Comment: The real problem was that you created an array of _lists_ rather than an array of `[Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]` instances. The awkward design of the `New-WinUserLanguageList
` cmdlet is to blame for that, which is still worth addressing in an answer.

Comment: P.S.: As an aside, allow me to give you a language tip: by "actual" you probably meant "no longer relevant". ["actual" means something closer to "real"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=actual)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood that problem when I was trying to understand errors a little more. Creating a list of lists fixed the problem and cmdlet works as I needed. And yeah, wanted to close question, but don't know how. But at least people spent their time explaining things to me, which I really appreciate

Comment: Glad to hear it. In case it wasn't just a typo: it wasn't creating a list of _lists_ that fixed the problem, but a list of `WinUserLanguage` instances - which is what `New-WinUserLanguageList` _should_ allow you to do with _multiple_ languages - but currently doesn't. As for closing your question: you can _delete_ it, but - as in this case - that's not a good idea when answers have already been posted (and, as stated, your question is useful in that others may make the same mistake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following *commented* code snippets:

```
PS D:\PShell> ### Type mismatch

$langlist=$lang_en,$lang_ru

### Note the difference in type:

$langlist.gettype().Name                   ### Object[]

(Get-WinUserLanguageList).gettype().Name   ### List`1
```

> ```
> Object[]
> List`1
> ```

```
PS D:\PShell> ### Use the following:

$langlist = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$langlist.Clear()
$langlist.Add($lang_en[0])
$langlist.Add($lang_ru[0])

$langlist.gettype().Name                   ### List`1
```

> ```
> List`1
> ```

```
PS D:\PShell> <### The next cmdlet should work now:

set-winuserlanguagelist $langlist

<##>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that **you're using `New-WinUserLanguageList` *twice*, with *each* call returning a list**, so that `$langlist = $lang_en, $lang_ru` **mistakenly created an *array* of (single-item) lists** rather than **a single list with two items**, which caused the (nonsensically-sounding) type-mismatch error you saw.

**Very awkwardly, however, cmdlet `New-WinUserLanguageList` only allows you to specify *one* language, even though it returns a *list* type** (`[Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]]`).

That is, the following *should* work, but doesn't:

```
# Try to create the list with *2* entries
$langlist = New-WinUserLanguageList en-gb, ru  # !! Doesn't work, parameter type is [string]
```

Instead, you have to **initialize with *1* language and then add additional ones *later*, using the `.Add()` method**:

```
# Create the list with initially just 'en-gb'...
$langlist = New-WinUserLanguageList en-gb

# ... and then add the other language, 'ru'
# Because the list is strongly typed, it is sufficient to pass the language
# identifier, which implicitly creates a new
# [Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage] instance.
$langlist.Add('ru')

# Now you can modify the properties of $langlist[0] (en-gb)
# and $langlist[1] (ru)
# ...

# ... and pass the list of modified languages to Set-WinUserLanguageList:
Set-WinUserLanguageList $langlist
```

Alternatively, **to avoid the `.Add()` call, you could have used**:

```
$langlist = (New-WinUserLanguageList en-gb)[0], (New-WinUserLanguageList ru)[0]
```

Even though `$langlist` is then technically an *array* (a `[System.Object[]]` instance whose elements are of type `Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage`), passing it to `Set-WinUserLanguageList` works, because it is *implicitly* converted to the required list type.

Answer (score 0):

The **Set-WinUserLanguageList** cmdlet has evolved (at lease since Win 20H1) and the syntax is now very straightforward:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList 'fr-FR','en-US','en-GB'
```

If you want to add additional languages to the existing ones, you can use this code snippet:

```
$CurrentLanguageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList

$NewLanguageList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

foreach($Language in $CurrentLanguageList.LanguageTag){
    $NewLanguageList.Add($Language) | Out-Null
}

#Adding new languages here
$NewLanguageList.Add('de-DE') | Out-Null
$NewLanguageList.Add('ru-RU') | Out-Null

Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $NewLanguageList
```